# How to specify AWS credentials in a Log4Net configuration file?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, log4net, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to log to AWS CloudWatch via the [Log4Net AWS Logging Appender](https://github.com/aws/aws-logging-dotnet).  I've setup log4net.config file with log group and region and other required parameters.

I unclear as to how to add AWS credentials to the .config file.  The documentation states `To use a specific AWS credential profile add a Profile under the appender node`, but provides no example or documentation about what should be there.

Am I missing something simple in the documentation?

Comment: According to the docs it's using the .net SDK's default credential discovery: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-creds.html.